# How to integrate Login with linkedin in react-native or expo, expo dev-client?

Tags: react-native, expo, linkedin-api

> I already created an app on linkedin developer account https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps and i tried with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-linkedin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@smuxx/react-native-linkedin
> https://socket.dev/npm/package/@edose/react-native-linkedin